# How to set default checked item in NavigationView?

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

When I click on the `NavigationView` item its selection color changes. But I don't know how to check the first element by default.

```
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        return true;
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: What is this code about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add this

```
android:checked="true"
```

to your first item in the drawer menu. For example take a look at mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_home"
        android:checked="true"   //default set to check
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home"
        android:title="@string/home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_favourite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_favorite_black"
        android:title="@string/favourite"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_recent"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_recent"
        android:title="@string/recent"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"/>

</group>
```